# Python - problem with for loop (guess a color - game)

Tags: python

I'm new to python and i got a problem with my program. I'm trying to create 'guess a color - game' using for loop and here's my code:

```
from random import randint

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'black', 'pink']
generator = randint(0,len(colors)-1)
guess = input('guess a color: ')

for color in colors[generator]:
    if guess != colors[generator]:
        print('wrong, try again')
        guess = input('guess a color: ')
    elif guess == colors[generator]:
        break


print('yay, color was: ' + colors[generator])
```

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a very close look at your code output, you will notice that you put a space in your "blue" answer.  What it took in was " blue" which does not match.  Since your for loop stops at the number of letters in the randomly chosen color, it stopped and outputted the correct color.  What you should have instead, if you want to account for errant spaces, is the following:

```
from random import randint

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'black', 'pink']
generator = randint(0,len(colors)-1)
guess = input('guess a color: ')

while True: #you want to keep guessing until you actually get it
    if guess != colors[generator]:
        print('wrong, try again')
        guess = input('guess a color: ').strip() #strip() here removes spaces
    elif guess == colors[generator]:
        break

print('yay, color was: ' + colors[generator])
```

Comment: thank you! your explanation made me to understand what i did wrong there!